# When I past my SPA links in social media it is showing default meta tags only?

Tags: angular, angular-seo

I am using Angular 7 for SPA

Here is the link "https://adda.io/openings/sales-openings/1".

Above link has it own meta and title when inspect I can see the tags inside , But when I post it in any social media it shows the default homepage one only.

Check by pasting this link in any social media

```
import {Meta, Title} from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(meta: Meta, title: Title) {
        title.setTitle(metaTag.facility_management_software.title);
        meta.addTags(metaTag.facility_management_software.meta);
    }

<meta name="description"
          content="Enhance your apartment living experience online with the best Apartment Management Software, ADDA for Communication, Accounting and Facility Management. Secure your apartment gate with with ADDA Gatekeeper for foolproof security solution.">
```

it should show the real data

```
<meta name="description" content="Social Media Platform, Fintech Integrations, IoT, Home Automation we have it all! 3 products, 5 Apps, 7,00,000 users across 90 cities globally. Managing it all is a team of less than 20. Do you have it in you to join this team?">
```

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660611/angular-5-meta-description-not-working it does not affect the html from the page, and the social media apps "crawl" the html, not the DOM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 5 - Meta description not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660611/angular-5-meta-description-not-working)